# How do I transpose multiple rows to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, transpose

My first time reading a question on here.

I am working at a university and I have a table of student IDs and their supervisors, some of the students have one supervisor and some have two or three depending on their subject.

The table looks like this

```
ID  Supervisor
1   John Doe
2   Peter Jones
2   Sarah Jones
3   Peter Jones
3   Sarah Jones
4   Stephen Davies
4   Peter Jones
4   Sarah Jones
5   John Doe
```

I want to create a view that turns that into this:

```
ID  Supervisor 1    Supervisor 2    Supervisor 3
1   John Doe        
2   Peter Jones     Sarah Jones 
3   Peter Jones     Sarah Jones 
4   Stephen Davies  Peter Jones      Sarah Jones
5   John Doe
```

I have looked at PIVOT functions, but don't think it matches my needs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when a student gets a 4th supervisor? What happens when they get a 937th supervisor?

Comment: I think you are looking for somthing like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: HI Gvee, there can be more than a dozen supervisors, but never more than 3 live supervisors, the rest all have end dates so get filtered out.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on a windows server.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT was the right clue, it only needs a little 'extra' :)

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE (ID INT,Supervisor VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO @tt(ID,Supervisor)
VALUES
(1,'John Doe'),
(2,'Peter Jones'),
(2,'Sarah Jones'),
(3,'Peter Jones'),
(3,'Sarah Jones'),
(4,'Stephen Davies'),
(4,'Peter Jones'),
(4,'Sarah Jones'),
(5,'John Doe');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            'Supervisor ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Supervisor) AS VARCHAR(128)) AS supervisor_id,
            Supervisor
        FROM
            @tt
    ) AS tt
    PIVOT(
        MAX(Supervisor) FOR
        supervisor_id IN ([Supervisor 1],[Supervisor 2],[Supervisor 3])
    ) AS piv;
```

Result:

```
ID  Supervisor 1    Supervisor 2    Supervisor 3
1   John Doe        NULL            NULL
2   Peter Jones     Sarah Jones     NULL
3   Peter Jones     Sarah Jones     NULL
4   Peter Jones     Sarah Jones     Stephen Davies
5   John Doe        NULL            NULL
```

You will notice that the assignment to `Supervisor X` is done by ordering by the Supervisor-VARCHAR. If you want the ordering done differently, you might want to include an [Ordering] column; then change to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Ordering])`. Eg an [Ordering] column could be an `INT IDENTITY(1,1)`. I'll leave that as an excercise to you if that's what's really needed.